# A part of the Leontief matrix: something -> something

Tags: arrows, matrices, braces

I know this is probably not needed considering I have a matrix and such, but I would like to know what the best way would be for formatting something like this into LaTeX:

[image: Element -> Element (or Sector -> Sector in the case of Leontief matrices)]

Tried using matrices and tables but nothing that looks like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done here with stacks, in lieu of arrays.

```
\documentclass{arlticle}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\stackMath
\def\Xrightarrow#1{\xrightarrow{\makebox[3ex]{$\scriptstyle#1$}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\overbrace{\Longstack{%
  P \Xrightarrow{0.1} P\cr
  T_1 \Xrightarrow{0} P\cr
  T_2 \Xrightarrow{0.2} P\cr
  C \Xrightarrow{0.4} P}}^P
\quad\overbrace{\Longstack{%
  P \Xrightarrow{0.4} T_1\cr
  T_1 \Xrightarrow{0.1} T_1\cr
  T_2 \Xrightarrow{0.15} T_1\cr
  C \Xrightarrow{0.3} T_1}}^{T_1}
\quad\overbrace{\Longstack{%
  P \Xrightarrow{0.6} T_2\cr
  T_1 \Xrightarrow{0} T_2\cr
  T_2 \Xrightarrow{0.1} T_2\cr
  C \Xrightarrow{0.25} T_2}}^{T_2}
\quad\overbrace{\Longstack{%
  P \Xrightarrow{0.2} C\cr
  T_1 \Xrightarrow{0.1} C\cr
  T_2 \Xrightarrow{0.3} C\cr
  C \Xrightarrow{0.2} C}}^{C}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, wasn't too sure how to do arrays and such! Works though!

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of `\overbrace` and `\overset` to get the desired output. `\overset` allows you to place something on top of something else (in your case the numbers on top of the arrow).

The best way of formatting seems to me to put the array in the `\overbrace` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amstext}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \overbrace{\begin{array}{ccc}
        p&\overset{0,1}{\to}&p\\
        T_1&\overset{0,2}{\to}&p\\
        T_2&\overset{0,3}{\to}&p\\
        C&\overset{0,4}{\to}&p\\
    \end{array}}^{P}\quad
    \overbrace{\begin{array}{ccc}
        p&\overset{0,1}{\to}&T_1\\
        T_1&\overset{0,2}{\to}&T_1\\
        T_2&\overset{0,3}{\to}&T_1\\
        C&\overset{0,4}{\to}&T_1\\
    \end{array}}^{T_1}\quad
    \overbrace{\begin{array}{ccc}
        p&\overset{0,1}{\to}&T_2\\
        T_1&\overset{0,2}{\to}&T_2\\
        T_2&\overset{0,3}{\to}&T_2\\
        C&\overset{0,4}{\to}&T_2\\
    \end{array}}^{T_2}\quad
    \overbrace{\begin{array}{ccc}
        p&\overset{0,1}{\to}&C\\
        T_1&\overset{0,2}{\to}&C\\
        T_2&\overset{0,3}{\to}&C\\
        C&\overset{0,4}{\to}&C\\
    \end{array}}^{C}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this:
[image]